# adjective from business

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I am looking for a word like industrial but with the root of business. Something that fits in here:

> the [industrial(your word here)] applications of mathematics

I looked for adjectives from *business* but found nothing. How would you express what I am looking for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no specific adjective form of *business*. Instead, *business* is generally used as a [noun adjunct (or attributive noun)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct):

> the *business* applications of mathematics

Answer (score 3):

The adjective that typically goes with *business* is ***commercial***:

> the *commercial* applications

However, there’s really no need of that, since *business* makes a perfectly fine [noun adjunct](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/noun-adjuncts/info):

> A ***noun adjunct***, also called an *attributive noun*, is when one noun is used to give an attribute to another noun, like *dog catcher, dog food, house sitter, heart surgery, running shoes, employee compensation*, and *Peter Principle*. It is an alternative to a prepositional phrase, like *food for dogs* or *surgery of the heart*. A predicate test can be used to distinguish a noun adjunct from an adjective.

In other words, in a *business application*, the word *business* is a noun not an adjective because it fails the predicate test:

> *The application is business. [***WRONG***: therefore not an adjective]

Whereas with *commercial* passes it:

> The application is commercial. [***RIGHT***: therefore yes an adjective]

However, *business* doesn’t need to be an adjective, nor does it need to be turned into one.  It’s perfectly fine to use nouns to modify other nouns in *noun–noun* compounds like this.

Treat it as a compound noun with a space in it if you prefer. *Babysitter* and *baby food* are both the same sort of word, and the space in the latter is an orthographic red herring that tricks people who are too bent on misapplying old-fashioned Latin POS assignments to English.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the adjectives *managerial*, *financial*, and *consumer* to describe business-related applications of mathematics. They may be too specific for what you need, so you may be forced to specify which branch of business you're referring to with any of the business-related adjectives suggested so far.

Answer (score 0):

You could say "the professional application of mathematics" and it should include the industrial application as well. (If you could provide some context i could be more specific , so please send me a message with a context if you need any more help ).Hope this helped you !

Answer (score -4):

I support commercial and mercantile

Comment: Welcome to ELU! Could you explain how these fit the word they are looking for (preferably with definitions)? You might like to check out the [tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center on how to answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).